# Map object to type of a key of that object

Tags: typescript

Given:

```
interface GenericType<G> = {
    objectKey: G
},

const convert = (arg: {[key: string]: GenericType<any>}) =>
    Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(arg).map(([key, value]) => [key, value.objectKey])

const converted = convert({
    foo: {objectKey: "hello world"}
    bar: {objectKey: false}
})

// should return {foo: "hello world", bar: false}
```

How would I type this so that TypeScript knows the type of `converted` is `{foo: string, bar: boolean}`? Right now, the best I can get to (see [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=6#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgOIRNYCAqBPABwgB5UA%20ZAbwFgAoZB5AewCMArCBMAaQjwC40dAL506CJiADOYZBJAA3aLIC8yYjmQQAHpBAATKVQDaAaz6CZUUAHMAuoPSZruQiTgg8ZYWQAUcKBtBHABKQUpkYwAFKCYiKDA8ZFBkczwmGGQcByzjAHJWDi5ePDy7AG5kYWQVCgi6RmQoCDAAVygQZAB5dk4wADoYWIBbAFFwawgpXx6igYwwSemAmxD%204bgCX18zPgAaZAU4ABtWiDsQmopdvAOj04h%20wr6Si8u4Iwjo2PjE5M60hksjkcPlnsU%20GVKqJaDDxJIZHJJEoEhB9DUkYplL4aPRGDAmExwuCeBZkAAiAAWEGOxyYyAA7kwoMd9OThHsGowWAFib0IQJkPBjlIIDDhCEgA)) is that TypeScript infers the type is `{foo: unknown, bar: unknown}`.

Comment: Please include your attempts, as text formatted as code, in the question itself, not only on an external site.

Comment: You probably meant to use `T[Property]["objectKey"]`: https://tsplay.dev/NB8edW

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
const convert = <T extends Record<string, {objectKey: any}>>(arg: T) => 
Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(arg).map(([key, value]) => [key, value.objectKey])) as {[O in keyof T] : T[O]['objectKey']}

const converted = convert({
    foo: {objectKey: "hello world"},
    bar: {objectKey: false}
})

// return {foo: string, bar: boolean}
```

Comment: Wonderful. Thank you! I assume this has to do with the difference between Record type and `{[key: string]: any}`?